# javascript evaluate an assignment if(x=myfunc())

Tags: javascript, boolean, variable-assignment

I opened a js file that I wrote a while back and although it's working, I thought I spotted an error. (JS is not my primary language)

I had this:

```
if( myvar = fieldval.match(mypattern))
  {
     //Do Stuff
  }
```

So I think I get it. Is this a correct statement?:
A javascript assignment operation evaluates to the value being assigned.

I tested on w3schools

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var str="The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain"; 
var patt1=/ain/gi;
var test
document.write(test=str.match(patt1));
</script>
```

and it writes "ain,AIN,ain,ain" where I might have expected it to write "true" or not to write at all because boolean true is not a string. Is my line of thought and then ultimate conclusion correct. (I ask about my line of thought on this because I do not have a lot of formal CS training.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a correct statement. The new value of `myvar` is tested:

```
if ( myvar = fieldval.match(mypattern) )
```

When the [`String.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method cannot find a match, it returns `null`. `!!null === false`, so the `if-block` is not evaluated. When any non-empty match is found, the condition is true, and the block is evaluated.

In this case, it is very likely that the if-statement is correct, and that the following is intended:

```
if ( (myvar = fieldval.match(mypattern)) !== null )
```

Comment: Thank you, but as a matter of style I think I'll follow @JP Richardson's advice and re-work that piece of code, or at least put a comment by it.

Comment: The extra check for `myvar !== ''` is redundant. The function match returns an array, and an array always evaluates to true, even if it's empty or contains one empty string. In short, empty matches also cause the block to be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Rob W is correct, however it's extremely poor practice to put an assignment in an if statement like that. In the future, anyone coming along (including yourself) will scratch their head at that statement to determine if that's what you really meant.

I highly recommend Douglas Crockford's talk: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=taaEzHI9xyY It'll make anyone (Js dev or not) a better developer for watching it because you'll consider the implications of your coding style and what future maintainers might assume.

Comment: +1 because that's exactly what happened. I saw my own code and thought "What was I doing?"

Comment: Wow, that's an hour long video. I'm at work right now and can't take time to watch it. Maybe I'll get back to it later. As a matter of style would you (or other JS developers if you can speak for them) find it acceptable to use that type of condional test as long is there is a comment near it explaining what it does?

Comment: It's really worth time, maybe watch 5 to 10 mins sometime to see if it's worth it to you to watch anymore. I think as long as you put a comment stating that the `=` (assignment) in the conditional check is what you meant, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

The function string.match() returns an array of matches, or null if no matches are found. The code works because null evaluates to false in an if statement, while an array evaluates to true.

So indeed, the result of str.match is stored in myvar and then myvar is evaluated as boolean. It works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`match` returns an array of matching values, not boolean. Use `test` instead.

Comment: In this case, the pattern is non-empty, so `!!str.match(pattern) === !!pattern.test(str)`.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the match is empty, because you get an array of matches. An array containing exactly one empty string also evaluates to true. In fact, an empty array even evaluates to true.

Even this works:
`if ([]) { alert("Empty array is true.") }`

Comment: In the post there was: "where I might have expected it to write 'true'". I assumed OP wants to have booleans for possible later use of `myvar`...